# boundary of the intersection of two open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $R^+$ be positive numbers. So $0$ is its boundary. Question 1: can we also say $+\infty$ is its boundary? in a general sense?

Let $P$ be a collection of symmetric positive definite matrices of certain dimension. I understand its closure is the symmetric semi-positive definite matrices $SP$. So the boundary is $SP/P$. Question 2: Similarly, can we say that the matrices with elements going to $+\infty$ is also its boundary, so long as they are symmetric positive definite? I think I need a rigorous definition here.

Question 3: what is the boundary of $P\oplus R^+$? Is it $\mathbf{0}\oplus 0$, $\mathbf{0}\oplus (+\infty)$,    $(+\infty)\oplus 0$, or $(+\infty)\oplus (+\infty)$?

Comment: Not every question involving sets is about set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundary of a set $A$ that is a subset of a topological space $X$, depends not only on $A$, but also on $X$. You only mentioned that $A=\mathbb R^+$, but not what is $X$.

- With $X=\mathbb R$, we have $\partial A=\{0\}$.
- With $X=\overline {\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ (extended reals), we have $\partial A=\{0,\infty\}$.
- With $X=\mathbb C$, we hace $\partial A=[0,\infty)$.

Likewise in the case of symmetrci positive deifnite matrices, you should specify/make yourself clear, what the (natural?) surrounding space is. I think the natural choice would be all real matrices. If you want to add infinite elements, you need to specify how many infinite elemets you add and define the topology suitably (and I guess you rather shouldn't)